# Argparse: either (x and y) OR (z)

Tags: python, argparse

I have the following code:

```
def main():
    argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'DESCRIPTION',epilog = 'Please see README.MD for guidance on how to use this script')
    argParser.add_argument('-i', '--inFile', action='store',type=str, required = True, help = 'Input config file')
    argParser.add_argument('-o', '--outFile', action = 'store', default = sys.stdout, type = argparse.FileType('w'), required = False, help = 'Output VCD File')
#   generate_config_group = argParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    argParser.add_argument('-g', '--generate-config', action='store_true',help='Generate empty config File to fill')
    args = argParser.parse_args()

    print("\nExecuting Script:" + str(sys.argv[0]))
    print("  config file:" + str(args.inFile))
    print("  vcd outFile:" + str(args.outFile.name))

    if args.generate-config:
        if generate_config():
            return 'config generated. see sample-config.ini. You will need to edit these values for this script to run successfully'
```

I want it so that you either need BOTH -i and -o arguments OR the -g argument. Right now if you supply -g, it still gets mad that you haven't supplied -i and -o. What is the way to do this? I have heard subparsers might be the way, but I see that with those, you call the command differently - `script.py subparser_name -flags`.

I don't want that. I only want -o and -i and -g as possible flags.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could solve this from *argparse* args, but I'd set them all `required=False` and after parsing, do a manual check (e.g. `if not ((i and o) or g):` (Boole's laws could be applied to simplify), `return error`).

Comment: `inFile` is specified `required`!  Of course it's going to complain if you don't provide it.  You have a good default for `outFile`, so there's no need to worry whether it's provided or not.  Use a `print(args)` to see what the parser sees with various inputs.  Once that's clear implement the post-parsing tests.

Answer (score 0):

Why not update the IF at the end to something like:

```
import warnings
if (args.generate-config) or (args.inFile and args.outFile):
    if generate_config():
        return 'config generated. see sample-config.ini. You will need to edit these values for this script to run successfully'

else:
   warnings.warn("When executing script i and o or g are required.")
```

Comment: Typo: `args.generate-config`?

Comment: Are you referring to second IF? I copied that from initial question. Cheers.